Time setting problems with ubuntu 24.04
I changed from Ubuntu 20.04 to 24.04. Now the clock shows the wrong time (3 hours early). When I opened the system settings to fix this, the program crushes when I click on "Date and time".
Can anybody help me?

Please note that the zero:es in version numbers are significant, do not leave out.

It seems like the timezone database on your system may not have the correct or complete information, or the necessary timezone files might not be installed. Here's a step-by-step guide to troubleshoot and fix this issue:
1.Check if the time zone is installed:
First, check if the tzdata package, which provides timezone information, is installed and up-to-date.
Run the following command:
sudo apt update

sudo apt install tzdata

This will ensure that the latest timezone data is installed.
2.List available time zones:
Check if Europe/Berlin is listed among the available time zones:
timedatectl list-timezones | grep Europe

If Europe/Berlin is not listed, it means your system is missing the required timezone data or there’s an issue with the timezone database.
3.Manually reconfigure tzdata (if needed):
You can also manually reconfigure the tzdata package to ensure the correct timezone files are installed:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

During this process, you'll be prompted to select your region (e.g., Europe) and your city (e.g., Berlin).
4.Set the timezone again:
Once you've verified that the timezone is available, try setting it again:
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin

If everything is working properly, this command should now succeed without any error.
Let me know if the issue persists!

OK, I did that.
After entering "sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" I got this output:
"Current default time zone: 'Europe/Berlin'
Local time is now:      Tue Oct  8 20:34:38 UTC 2024.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Oct  8 20:34:38 UTC 2024."
So there is no difference between local and universal time.
After entering "sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin" I got again "Failed to set time zone: Invalid or not installed time zone 'Europe/Berlin'"

It seems like there's an issue with how your system is handling time zones. Let's go through a few steps to resolve this:
Check if the time zone files are properly installed: Run this command to check if the time zone files exist for 'Europe/Berlin':
ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/
If you don't see "Berlin" in the list, there might be a missing or corrupted time zone database.
Reinstall the time zone data:                                                                                                  sudo apt install --reinstall tzdata

Ok, that solved it. Thank you!

There is a known issue with the latest tzdata on Ubuntu 24.04, where changing timezones has no effect and seems not to produce any errors.
While timedatectl shows the correct timezone information, the top bar consistently displays the UTC date.
Current Status (as of Nov 5, 2024): The issue persists with the latest updates on Ubuntu 24.04. This has been confirmed among colleagues who recently migrated to this version.
Temporal solution for now - to downgrade the version.
This one worked for me and my colleagues: 2022a-0ubuntu1 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tzdata_2022a-0ubuntu1_all.deb).
You can also explore other versions available on launchpad

Do you have a link to this "known issue"?

@OlafDietsche
This thread helped me to understand where to look and what to change: https://github.com/Alexays/Waybar/issues/3024

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This bug still exists in Ubuntu 24.04.1.  I upgraded two laptops from 22.04 and both resulted in an inability to set the time zone correctly.  The output of date was always in UTC, though the time zone was listed as the bogus Canada time zone.  Using that tzdata_2022a-0ubuntu1_all.deb fixed the problem on both machines; the time is correct and the date command shows the time zone is now EST.

Bug submitted:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/2092236

Open a terminal (bash prompt); a window with a $ and a blinking cursor will appear...
So, do not type $ - that is "the prompt", to indicate what YOU are expected to type a command and arguments. The other lines comes as output from those 'commands'
Note: hit Enter at the end of each command
Now; this will display the terse help page for date:
$ date --help
Usage: date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
  or:  date [-u|--utc|--universal] [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]
Display date and time in the given FORMAT.
With -s, or with [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]], set the date and time.

...

... the text beyond this tells a lot of detail.
Among that information you find that adding -s to the arguments will SET the time and date.
Also note that you are likely to need a sudo to do that successfully, as that writes into the hardware RTC (real time clock).
So a "sudo date -s [MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]]" should do this: e.g.
$ sudo date -s 100410302024
for 2024-10-04@10:30.
Verify by a simple
$ date

to set the systemclock use ntpdate command that uses a pool of ntp servers in pool.ntp.org to set your time
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org

After this, you need to set the hardware clock to the recently synced system time using
sudo hwclock -w

To set the clock automatically you should use systemd-timesyncd.service
sudo systemctl enable systemd-timesyncd.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service

then:
timedatectl set-ntp yes


This didn't change anything. Is it possible that the problem is a wrong timezone-setting? What concerns me more is the fact, that the settings-menu keeps crashing when I click on the "Date and time"-button.

With timedatectl command you can check your computer timezone And if there is a problem, you can choose the right time zone with the switches of the same command

Make sure that systemd-timesyncd.service is active and working properly

When I use timedatectl to set the timezone I get the following message:
xxx@xxx:~$ sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service
[sudo] Passwort für xxx:
xxx@xxx:~$ timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
Failed to set time zone: Invalid or not installed time zone 'Europe/Berlin'

I have provided a solution for you in a new answer
